# linking my text file to my java code

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am a beginner at java and doing an exercise where I need to link a text file for my code to read through.

here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Java116 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String[] namn          = new String[100];
    double[] perMån        = new double[100];
    double[] perMinDag     = new double[100];
    double[] perMinÖvr     = new double[100];
    double[] friaDag       = new double[100];
    double[] friÖvr        = new double[100];

    Scanner fil = new Scanner(new File("mobildata.txt"));
    int n = 0;

    while (fil.hasNext()) {
        namn [n] = fil.next();
        perMån[n]       = fil.nextDouble();
        perMinDag[n]    = fil.nextDouble();
        perMinÖvr[n]    = fil.nextDouble();
        friaDag[n]      = fil.nextDouble();
        friÖvr[n]       = fil.nextDouble();
        n++;
    }

    while (true) {
        String s =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hur många minuter ringer du per månad \n" +
        "Under dagrid respettive övrig tid? ");

        if (s == null)
            break;

        Scanner input = new Scanner (s);
        double minDag = input.nextDouble();
        double minÖvr = input.nextDouble();
        double billigast = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        int index = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            double antalDag = Math.max(minDag-friaDag[i], 0);
            double antalÖvr = Math.max(minÖvr-friÖvr[i], 0);
            double kostnad  = perMån[i] + antalDag*perMinDag[i] + antalÖvr*perMinÖvr[i];
            if (kostnad < billigast) {
                billigast = kostnad;
                index = i;
            }
        }
        String resultat = String. format("%.2f", billigast);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                namn[index]+ "är billigast.\n" +"kostnad: " + resultat + "kr / månad" );
    }

}
}
```

the error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: mobildata.txt (The 
system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
at Java116.main(Java116.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

I have added the text file to the java file where all my other files are located when using Intellij

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The application is probably looking in the wrong directory. In IntelliJ IDEA, make sure the Project tool window is open (View -> Tool Windows -> Project). In the Project window, select "Project Files" (see screenshot).

[image: Screenshot]

You will then see where your mobildata.txt file is located. Move it (drag-and-drop) to the top-level project folder, which is probably the current working directory when your program runs. Re-run and see if this fixes it.

Comment: Hi Klitos, thank you for the answer, I cant seem to find the "Project Files". could you maybe send a screenshot.

Comment: @Biogrid screenshot added